# cannot use var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter')

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

I need to generate test report in Protractor. I went through some tutorials and those tutorials are not clear to me.

when I tried to install npm, following error occurs.

[image]

After running this folder called node_modules is created. But, I don't get why I cannot install npm. Please help.

-edit -

I'm using [this](http://www.blaiseliu.com/set-up-protractor-html-screenshot-reporter/)tutorial to generate protractor reports.

and I added `var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter')` to my `conf.js`
Here is my complete file.

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['invoice.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
  },
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
  }

    var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

      var reporter=new HtmlReporter({
        baseDirectory: './protractor-result', // a location to store screen shots.
        docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
        docName:    'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
    });

    exports.config = {
        seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
        specs: ['invoice.js'],

        onPrepare: function() {
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
        }
    }
}
```

Following error occurs.

[image]

Please tell me what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those aren't errors, they're warnings (because you don't have a `package.json` file in your project). As far as I can tell from that log, the module installed fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm new to this. Now, I have some more problems. Can you please look at edied question. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Posted an answer with a - hopefully! - working config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `conf.js` is formatted wrong - you can't define variables within an object definition. It should look something like this:

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: './protractor-result', // a location to store screen shots.
    docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
    docName: 'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
});

exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['invoice.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
  },
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
  }
}
```

Note that I've never used Protractor, so I can't guarentee this is a working config, but it should sort your syntax errors.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer. now the script is running. I gave a folder in my desktop as baseDirectory. So, now I'm suppose to get screenshots for that folder ryt? but, it's not hapening. :(

Comment: Seeing as you prefixed the `baseDirectory` with `./`, I imagine the path will be relative to the folder where the `conf.js` file is stored.

Comment: Still Cannot find the screen shots. :( anyway, I'll accept your answer since you helped me a lot. :)

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help! It might be worth posting another question now that you've narrowed down the issue, hopefully someone with more experience with Protractor might be able to help you.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for your help :)